# How does JavaScript "this" works with ${}?

Tags: javascript, object, this

I have the following code:

```
module.export = { 
  OBJECT: { 
    "key01": "value01", 
    "key02": "value02" },
  ARRAY: {
    NESTED_ARRAY: [
      `my.object.${this.OBJECT.key01}`,
      `my.object.${this.OBJECT.key02}`,
      ]
  }
}

console.log(ARRAY.NESTED_ARRAY[0] === my.object.value01)
```

How to get the above console.log statement to be true?

Comment: console.log(true) ?

Answer (score 1):

Change console.log(ARRAY.NESTED_ARRAY[0] === my.object.value01) to 
console.log(ARRAY.NESTED_ARRAY[0] !== my.object.value01)

Comment: You sir, are correct. my. will be undefined. I would have upvoted your answer but I didn't have enough rep.